# Can I target particular iPhone models in image assets?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

The image assets Xcode feature lets me load different bitmaps for different display resolutions (1✕, 2✕, 3✕), different device families (iPad, iPhone, Mac) and different size classes (any, compact, regular).

[image: image assets UI sample]

Is there a way to specify separate bitmaps for different iPhone models, too? For example, can I specify a different bitmap to be loaded on an iPhone 6 and a different bitmap for an iPhone 6 Plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The best you can do is having a specific Retina 4'' @2x image aside from the regular @2x one.

Answer (score 0):

with your example, and as things currently stand, yes because the iPhone6+ is the only device currently running triple scale.  This will inevitably change however.  But generally no, you can't.  If you need more control than the boxes provided give you then you'd need to do the sorting in a switch statement or similar in your code...

Comment: But both iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 use the double scale, so that won’t work either?

Comment: And iphone4 & 4s too, yup